# Get rid of "Disable AMT Profile Synchronization Pop-up"

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I found *Disable AMT Profile Synchronization Pop-up* item in my *Program and Features* section of Control Panel (Windows 7 x64). I tried to get rid of it, but all three methods known to me failed:

- remove with *Uninstall* button in *Program and Features* (and rebooted Windows, as ordered to),
- [Lenovo Support](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/pl/en/downloads/ds000689)'s solution -- adding entiry to Windows registry brings no effect,
- [Lenovo Forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/What-the-h-l-is-quot-Disable-AMT-Profile-Synchronization-Pop-up/m-p/2229291#M67436), solution -- I don't have *Intel AMT* item in *Security > Anti-theft* group in BIOS (I only have *Computrace*, which I have disabled, but still -- no effect).

Are there any other methods or solutions that I can try to get rid of this from my system?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no! The only reasonable solution is to ignore that entry.